# pl sql payment calculation

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need help with PVA calculation in PL/SQL .I have formula:

Annuity = r * PVA Ordinary / [1 – (1 + r)<sup>-n</sup>]

Where:

- PVA Ordinary = Present value of an ordinary annuity
- r = Effective interest rate
- n = Number of periods.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV9IZ.png)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include **YOUR** attempt at a solution and the issues/errors with **YOUR** attempt. StackOverflow is not a service where we do your homework/job for you, **YOU** need to make the initial attempt and then we can help with errors and debugging. Also, your image shows a table but the text says you want to use `DBMS_OUTPUT` which will display text, and not a table; which do you want?

Comment: I think I have corrected the formula as the markdown formatting was missing for the `-n` ; however, please check it to make sure it is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for you have edited formula. actually the result should be as first row 1. 14.08.2022, 1881.80, 1 746.80, 135.00, 7 253.20. then second row 2. 14.09.2022, 1881.80, 1 746.80, 135.00, 7 253.20 and so on

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```sql
DECLARE
  principal NUMBER := 9000;
  r         NUMBER := 0.015;
  n         NUMBER := 5;
  start_dt  DATE   := DATE '2022-07-14';
  payment   NUMBER := r * principal / (1 - POWER(1 + r, -n));
  amt       NUMBER := principal;
  interest  NUMBER;
  pmt_dt    DATE;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. n LOOP
    pmt_dt := ADD_MONTHS(start_dt, i);
    pmt_dt := pmt_dt + CASE pmt_dt - TRUNC(pmt_dt, 'IW')
                       WHEN 5 THEN 2 -- Saturday
                       WHEN 6 THEN 1 -- Sunday
                              ELSE 0 -- Weekday
                       END;
    interest := amt * r;
    amt := amt - payment + interest;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      TO_CHAR(i, 'fm0')
      || ', ' || TO_CHAR(pmt_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD (DY)')
      || ', ' || TO_CHAR(payment, '9990.00')
      || ', ' || TO_CHAR(interest, '990.00')
      || ', ' || TO_CHAR(payment - interest, '9990.00')
      || ', ' || TO_CHAR(amt, '9990.00')
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 1, 2022-08-15 (MON),  1881.80,  135.00,  1746.80,  7253.20
> 2, 2022-09-14 (WED),  1881.80,  108.80,  1773.01,  5480.19
> 3, 2022-10-14 (FRI),  1881.80,   82.20,  1799.60,  3680.59
> 4, 2022-11-14 (MON),  1881.80,   55.21,  1826.60,  1853.99
> 5, 2022-12-14 (WED),  1881.80,   27.81,  1853.99,    -0.00
> ```

Or, in SQL using a `MODEL` clause:

```sql
WITH data (id, start_date, principal, rate, period ) AS (
  SELECT 1, DATE '2022-07-14', 9000, 0.015, 5 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT pmt_dt + CASE pmt_dt - TRUNC(pmt_dt, 'IW')
                WHEN 5 THEN 2
                WHEN 6 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END AS pmt_dt,
       ROUND(payment, 2) AS payment,
       ROUND(interest, 2) AS interest,
       ROUND(payment - interest, 2) AS reduction,
       ROUND(balance, 2) AS balance
FROM   data
MODEL
  PARTITION BY (id)
  DIMENSION BY (1 AS key)
  MEASURES (
    start_date,
    principal,
    rate,
    period,
    DATE '1900-01-01' AS pmt_dt,
    rate * principal / (1 - POWER(1 + rate, -period)) AS payment,
    0 AS interest,
    0 AS balance
  )
  RULES SEQUENTIAL ORDER ITERATE (100) UNTIL (balance[ITERATION_NUMBER+1] <= 0) (
    payment[ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = payment[1],
    pmt_dt[ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = ADD_MONTHS(start_date[1], ITERATION_NUMBER+1),
    interest[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1]
      = COALESCE(balance[ITERATION_NUMBER],principal[1]) * rate[1],
    balance[ITERATION_NUMBER+1]
      = COALESCE(balance[ITERATION_NUMBER],principal[1])
        - payment[1] + interest[ITERATION_NUMBER+1]
  )
ORDER BY id, key
```

Which outputs:

> | PMT_DT | PAYMENT | INTEREST | REDUCTION | BALANCE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 15-AUG-22 | 1881.8 | 135 | 1746.8 | 7253.2 |
> | 14-SEP-22 | 1881.8 | 108.8 | 1773.01 | 5480.19 |
> | 14-OCT-22 | 1881.8 | 82.2 | 1799.6 | 3680.59 |
> | 14-NOV-22 | 1881.8 | 55.21 | 1826.6 | 1853.99 |
> | 14-DEC-22 | 1881.8 | 27.81 | 1853.99 | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=19fba0ac8c6802d82fa71c0f5c8b6c7d)*

Comment: thanks you sooo much) yes i could understand where are my mistakes finally)

Comment: MT0, Can you suggest some very good articles to read more about Model clause.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai It is documented with the [`SELECT` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.htm) other than that just search the internet for "oracle model clause"